# how to start a new line inside a single <td> with bootstrap-vue b-table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create a table using vue.js as frontend and bootstrap-vue for css styles.
The generated table html should be like:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>item_1_1<br/>item_1_2<br/>item_1_3</td><td>item_1_4<br/>item_1_5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>item_2_1<br/>item_2_2</td><td>item_2_3</td></tr>
</table>
```

So as you can see, inside every td tag, there can be multiple items. Every item takes a single line. And the number of items is not fixed.
In bootstrap-vue, there is a b-table component:

```
<b-table :items="items"></b-table>
```

It binds data to items:

```
data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { r1c1: 40, r1c2: 'Dickerson', r1c3: 'Macdonald' },
          { r2c1: 21, r2c2: 'Larsen', r2c3: 'Shaw' }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Every single element from items takes one single cell in the b-table.
My question is how to add new lines for a single item here, like if I want r1c1 to be like: `40<br/>20`. I tried adding '\n' but it ended up in the webpage a space. Please help, many thanks.

Comment: Its in the dokumentation - check for scoped field slots - there you can customize the interrior an item declaration

Comment: @Estradiaz thank you very much. Found what you mentioned in the 'Displaying raw HTML' section and it works.

Comment: [Supplement] One thought about this compared to plain bootstrap: I used to loop data using v-for in vue.js with plain bootstrap. As long as the data is in listed in order, it will work. While using bootstrap-vue, I have to organize my data in a strict Array[dict] way so it can be binded to b-table. Further, some style control might get mixed into the data, and needs methods to help deal with. Hard to say bootstrap-vue makes it easier compared to vue.js + bootstrap. Not sure if I'm right about this.